# How to find horizontal and vertical distance variation between 2 objects

Tags: c#, math, image-processing, computer-vision, emgucv

I'm trying to find the horizontal and vertical variation between 2 objects in EMGU CV by finding the distance between their centroid. The bottom object is always fixed, the top object moves during production. I'm using this formula - ((x1 - x2) * (x1 - x2) + (y1 - y2) * (y1 - y2));

However, this gives a single value of variations in any direction. I'm trying to find the movement variation of top object horizontaly(left/right) and vertically(top/down) with reference to the fixed bottom object. How do I do this? Please help.

Comment: corrected that.

Comment: The formule you use gives the distance between the objects. As i understand you need diffX = x2 - x1 and diffY = y2 - y1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this problem by doing this : 
Using the centroid of the fixed object as the center of a circle i calculated the shifting on the top object like this : Math.Atan2(nydiff, nxdiff) * 180.0 / Math.PI

Answer (score 0):

*You're trying to find the horizontal and vertical variation between 2 objects by finding the distance between their centroids.*

```
Horizontal / x-direction:
d_x = |x_1 - x_2|

Vertical / y-direction:
d_y = |y_1 - y_2|
```

*You're using this formula:*

```
((x1 - x2) * (x1 - x2) + (y1 - y2) * (y1 - y2));
```

This by the way is called the [euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance#Distance_in_Euclidean_space).

And for movement variation you probably need to do this for two consecutive timesteps calculating the difference of the distances:

```
v_x(t=1) = d_x(t=1) - d_x(t=0)
```

Comment: Hi, whats t in your equation?

Comment: t indicates the time of your measurement (timestep)

Comment: Hi, I used a different approach. Using the centroid of the fixed object as the center of a circle i calculated the shifting on the top object like this : Math.Atan2(nydiff, nxdiff) * 180.0 / Math.PI